MAKEFILE: "No rule to make target..." error on using source files from recursive subfolder search
I'm trying to build a makefile to compile under linux a program made with Code::Blocks on windows (so, i have no working makefile to look at).
The project is big and the source files are in various subdirectories, so i've made my makefile this way:
# Main project folder
MyProject_PATH := ~/MyProject/
# Main Source Folder
SRC_PATH := $(MyProject_PATH)src
# All Source subfolders 
SRC_DIRS := $(shell find $(SRC_PATH) -type d)

# - Output folders
OBJ_PATH := $(MyProject_PATH)LINUXmake/obj-arm
BIN_PATH := $(MyProject_PATH)LINUXmake/bin-arm
# - Final executable name 
EXE      := $(BIN_PATH)/MyProject-arm

# get all .c and .cpp files
SRC   := $(foreach dir,$(SRC_DIRS),$(wildcard $(dir)/*.c) $(wildcard $(dir)/*.cpp))
# Define object files for each source file
OBJ := $(patsubst %.c,$(OBJ_PATH)/%.o,$(notdir $(SRC:.c=.o)))
OBJ := $(patsubst %.cpp,$(OBJ_PATH)/%.o,$(notdir $(OBJ:.cpp=.o)))

Then i have these rules section:
.PHONY: all show clean

# Rules for compiling .c files
%.o: %.c
    @echo "Compiling C file: $<"
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# Rules for compiling .cpp files
%.o: %.cpp
    @echo "Compiling C++ file: $<"
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# Rule to build the final target
$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    @echo "Linking objects to create target: $@"
    $(CXX) $(LDLIBS) $^ -o $@

# Rule to create output directories
$(shell mkdir -p $(OBJ_PATH) $(BIN_PATH))

# Rule to clean object files and the target
clean:
    $(RM) -r $(OBJ_PATH) $(BIN_PATH)

show:
    @printf "\nPaths: $(OBJ_PATH) $(BIN_PATH)\n"
    @printf "\nSource files:\n$(SRC)"
    @printf "\n\nObject files:\n$(OBJ)"
    @printf "\n\nCompiler:\n$(CC)"
    @printf "\n\nC++ Compiler:\n$(CXX)"
    @printf "\n\nC Flags:\n$(CFLAGS)"
    @printf "\n\nC++ Flags:\n$(CXXFLAGS)"
    @printf "\n\nInclude Flags:\n$(CPPFLAGS)"
    @printf "\n\nLinked Libraries:\n$(LDLIBS)"
    @echo   ""

But i always get this error:
make: *** No rule to make target 'cKeyboard.o', needed by '/home/buster/MyProject/LINUXmake/bin-arm/MyProject'.  Stop.

If i use the "show" target, i get this output:
Paths: ~/MyProject/LINUXmake/obj-arm ~/MyProject/LINUXmake/bin-arm

Source files:
 /home/buster/MyProject/src/cKeyboard.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/GUI_MainForm.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/MyProject_bitmaps.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/CommManager.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/cMSX.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/fMainForm.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/MSX_PG.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/MsgManager.cpp  /home/buster/MyProject/src/ClassiEventi/cBaseObjWithEvents.cpp  /home/buster/MyProject/src/cMSXTool/cMSXTool.cpp  /home/buster/MyProject/src/Comm/X_OS_Socket.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/Comm/serialib.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/Comm/BBBSerial.cpp    /home/buster/MyProject/src/CustomControls/cCCDCalibration/cCCDCal.cpp  /home/buster/MyProject/src/CustomControls/TAntiAliasedGauge/TAntiAliasedGauge.cpp  /home/buster/MyProject/src/CustomControls/TGradientButton/wxGradientButton.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/CustomControls/TGradientButton/wxGradientSwitch.cpp  /home/buster/MyProject/src/CustomControls/TPacket/cPacchetto.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/CustomControls/TPacket/TPacket.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/CustomControls/TPacket/cSigaretta.cpp    /home/buster/MyProject/src/CustomControls/TScannerImage/TScannerImage.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/CustomControls/TScannerImage/cResampler.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/CustomControls/TScannerImage/resampler.cpp  /home/buster/MyProject/src/CustomControls/TSigaTollerance/TSigaTolerance.cpp  /home/buster/MyProject/src/CustomControls/wxActiveArea/wxActiveArea.cpp  /home/buster/MyProject/src/CustomControls/wxPanelSensorBar/wxPanelSensorBar.cpp  /home/buster/MyProject/src/CustomControls/wxPngAnimator/wxpnganimator.cpp  /home/buster/MyProject/src/GUI_MainformParts/GUI_XMLManager.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/GUI_MainformParts/GUI_MSXT.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/GUI_MainformParts/GUI_MSXT (2).cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/GUI_MainformParts/GUI_UnusedControlEvents.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/GUI_MainformParts/GUI_GraphReader.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/GUI_MainformParts/GUI_TextBoxManagement.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/GUI_MainformParts/GUI_Charts.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/GUI_MainformParts/GUI_FileBrowser.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/GUI_MainformParts/GUI_RealTimeClock.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/GUI_MainformParts/GUI_SystemPages.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/GUI_MainformParts/GUI_KeysManagement.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/GUI_MainformParts/_DEBUG_STUFFS.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/I2C/24cXX.c /home/buster/MyProject/src/I2C/24cXX.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/I2C/i2cfunc.cpp  /home/buster/MyProject/src/MsxData/MsxGraph.cpp  /home/buster/MyProject/src/MSX_ClassParts/MSX_SendCommands.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/MSX_ClassParts/cTendenzaScarti.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/MSX_ClassParts/CCD_Averages.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/MSX_ClassParts/MSX_SalvaGrafici.cpp  /home/buster/MyProject/src/Utilities/Utilities.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/Utilities/StringUtils.cpp /home/buster/MyProject/src/Utilities/cGraphFile.cpp

Object files:
cKeyboard.o GUI_MainForm.o MyProject_bitmaps.o CommManager.o cMSX.o fMainForm.o MSX_PG.o MsgManager.o cBaseObjWithEvents.o cMSXTool.o X_OS_Socket.o serialib.o BBBSerial.o cCCDCal.o TAntiAliasedGauge.o wxGradientButton.o wxGradientSwitch.o cPacchetto.o TPacket.o cSigaretta.o TScannerImage.o cResampler.o resampler.o TSigaTolerance.o wxActiveArea.o wxPanelSensorBar.o wxpnganimator.o GUI_XMLManager.o GUI_MSXT.o GUI_MSXT (2).o GUI_UnusedControlEvents.o GUI_GraphReader.o GUI_TextBoxManagement.o GUI_Charts.o GUI_FileBrowser.o GUI_RealTimeClock.o GUI_SystemPages.o GUI_KeysManagement.o _DEBUG_STUFFS.o 24cXX.o 24cXX.o i2cfunc.o MsxGraph.o MSX_SendCommands.o cTendenzaScarti.o CCD_Averages.o MSX_SalvaGrafici.o Utilities.o StringUtils.o cGraphFile.o

I'm clearly missing something, but i can't sort what.
What should i do?

MyProject_PATH := ~/MyProject/ is an abomination.  It is pretty much never appropriate to put absolute paths to the project source in a makefile, and it's worse to put in a path starting with ~, because such a thing means different things in different contexts.  Instead, put the makefile in the root directory of the project, and express source paths relative to that.  Plan on making that folder the working directory when you build.

The mechanism you are using to identify the source files seems needlessly complex.  I'm a fan of listing files explicitly, even when there are a lot of them, but if you want to locate them automatically then why find the source directories and then scan them, instead of just finding the source files themselves, directly?  (And by the way, I would not account the number of source files you show in the question as even remotely "large".)

How important is it to you to put the object files in a separate directory from the sources?  The path of least resistances (and the conventional approach in the Unix tradition) is to build the objects to the same directories as their corresponding sources.  Also, if you insist on building to a separate directory then is it important to you to flatten the tree, as you seem to be doing?

@JohnBollinger:


About "~": i learned it in the hard way in the time after posting this question. About the use of "Home" folder, in general you're right, in this particular case Linux runs on WSL just as a "tool" to cross-compile for linux arm from a Windows machine, so it is not a big deal.


About find: what would be the line to find all the source files directly?


How important? 0 out fo 10. I thought It is just a byproduct of having the sources in different paths and just replace the common part of the string.



How about find $(SRC_PATH) -name '*.c' -o -name '*.cpp'?  find does glob matching.

I've found that the main problem was in the creation of the OBJ list:
by changing
OBJ := $(patsubst %.c,   $(OBJ_PATH)/%.o, $(notdir $(SRC:.c=.o)   ) )
OBJ := $(patsubst %.cpp, $(OBJ_PATH)/%.o, $(notdir $(OBJ:.cpp=.o) ) )

in
OBJ := $(patsubst $(SRC_PATH)/%.c,   $(OBJ_PATH)/%.o, $(SRC) )
OBJ := $(patsubst $(SRC_PATH)/%.cpp, $(OBJ_PATH)/%.o, $(OBJ) )

i've obtained that each .o files now has the same relative path to OBJ_PATH as the sources to SRC_PATH.
By using this in the pattern rules made the makefile works.
# Rules for compiling .c files
$(OBJ_PATH)/%.o: $(SRC_PATH)/%.c
    @echo "Compiling C file: $<"
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# Rules for compiling .cpp files
$(OBJ_PATH)/%.o: $(SRC_PATH)/%.cpp
    @echo "Compiling C++ file: $<"
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@


Since you wrote in comments that building object files to a separate subdirectory is not important to you, I would do it an easier way.  Keep your original %.o: %.c and %.o: %.cpp rules, and derive object file names by simply converting .c and .cpp to .o, without doing any path mangling.

@JohnBollinger: i don't understand this: when i do OBJ := $(patsubst $(SRC_PATH)/%.cpp, $(OBJ_PATH)/%.o, $(OBJ) ) i end up having the path with subdirectory of the source file also in the object file name. How can i remove it and still have the rule matching?

Using $(patsubst) for this is like asking Bobby Flay for a cheese sandwich.  He could do it, and the result would be fabulous, but you don't need anything like that level of sophistication for a slice of cheese between two pieces of bread. Just use a good old substitution reference: OBJ := $(SRC:.cpp=.o).  Similar for the .c to .o.  And the result will have the path in the filename.  That's as intended, and it will work fine as long as you're building the object files into the same directories as their corresponding sources.

This pattern rule:
%.o: %.cpp
    @echo "Compiling C file: $<"
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    

means: For a file that matches <SOMETHING>.cpp, make the file <SOMETHING>.o by
running the expansion of each line:
    @echo "Compiling C file: $<"
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    

as a shell command.
Your first source file, as shown by your make show output is:
/home/buster/MyProject/src/cKeyboard.cpp

so that pattern rule tells make how to make:
/home/buster/MyProject/src/cKeyboard.o

But the first object file needed by your $(EXE) target, as also shown
by make show, is:
cKeyboard.o

(= ./cKeyboard.o) and there is no rule to make that. Furthermore,
you do not want to make it. The file you want to make from:
/home/buster/MyProject/src/cKeyboard.cpp

is evidently:
$(OBJ_PATH)/cKeyboard.o 
    = ~/MyProject/LINUXmake/obj-arm 
    =  /home/buster/MyProject/LINUXmake/obj-arm/cKeyboard.o

Obviously, the same flaw affects the rule for %.o: %.c.
A pattern rule that would correctly compile /home/buster/MyProject/src/cKeyboard.cpp
would be:
$(OBJ_PATH)/%.o: $(SRC_PATH)/%.cpp
    @echo "Compiling C file: $<"
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

But that will not suffice for your source files in deeper subdirectories,
e.g. /home/buster/MyProject/src/ClassiEventi/cBaseObjWithEvents.cpp. There is
no single pattern rule that will match all the source files, dispersed
through a subdirectory tree.
For scenarios such as this, make provides the special VPATH variable,
with which you can specify a list of directories where make will search
for prerequisites of rules when they are not found in the current directory,
and treat them as if they were. See the [GNU Make manual: 4.5.1 VPATH: Search Path for All Prerequisites
Employing VPATH, you will set:
VPATH := $(SRC_DIRS)

and then your pattern rule can be:
$(OBJ_PATH)/%.o: %.cpp
    @echo "Compiling C file: $<"
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    

And likewise $(OBJ_PATH)/%.o: %.c .....
So far so good, but we have still to explain and rectify the fact that you
are generating:
$(OBJ) = cKeyboard.o ...

instead of what you need:
$(OBJ) = ~/MyProject/LINUXmake/obj-arm/cKeyboard.o ...

Which brings us to:
OBJ := $(patsubst %.c,$(OBJ_PATH)/%.o,$(notdir $(SRC:.c=.o)))
OBJ := $(patsubst %.cpp,$(OBJ_PATH)/%.o,$(notdir $(OBJ:.cpp=.o)))

For simplicity let's pretend that:
/home/buster/MyProject/src/cKeyboard.cpp

is the only source file. Then the first of those OBJ assignments means: Find all the words in the expansion of:
$(notdir $(SRC:.c=.o))
    = $(notdir $(/home/buster/MyProject/src/cKeyboard.cpp:.c=.o)
    = $(notdir /home/buster/MyProject/src/cKeyboard.cpp)    # Because there was no `.c=.o` substitution
    = cKeyboard.cpp
    

then replace any words in the result:
cKeyboard.cpp
    

that match <SOMETHING>.c with $(OBJ_PATH)/<SOMETHING>.o. There are no words in:
cKeyboard.cpp

that match <SOMETHING>.c, so the final result of that first OBJ assignment
remains
cKeyboard.cpp

The second OBJ assignment means: Find all the words in:
$(notdir $(OBJ:.cpp=.o))
    = $(notdir $(cKeyboard.cpp:.cpp=.o)
    = $(notdir cKeyboard.o)
    = cKeyboard.o
    

then replace any words on the result:
cKeyboard.o

that match <SOMETHING>.cpp with $(OBJ_PATH)/<SOMETHING>.o. There are no
words in:
cKeyboard.o

that match <SOMETHING>.cpp, so the final result of the second OBJ assignment
remains:
cKeyboard.o

instead of the desired
$(OBJ_PATH)/cKeyboard.o

Correct results will be obtained with:
CSRC := $(filter %.c,$(SRC))
CXXSRC := $(filter %.cpp,$(SRC))
OBJ := $(addprefix $(OBJ_PATH)/, $(notdir $(CSRC:.c=.o) $(CXXSRC:.cpp=.o)))

Then with the VPATH-assisted rules:
$(OBJ_PATH)/%.o: %.c
    ...
    
$(OBJ_PATH)/%.o: %.cpp
    ...

we're good to go.
An important word of caution though. A build system such as this still is (whether or not VPATH assisted),
in which source files file.(c|cpp|cc|cxx|...) from multiple subdirectories
will be compiled to object files file.o in a single directory, depends upon
every source filename file.(c|cpp|cc|cxx|...) being unique in all of the
source subdirectories. In any case like:
srcdirA/file.cpp

with:
srcdirB/file.c

and/or
srcdirC/file.cpp

make is instructed to compile all these source files to the same:
objdir/file.o

So it will do so for the first source file, say srcdirA/file.cpp;
then for the subsequent source files it will find that that objdir/file.o
is up to date and not bother to compile them.
This may be a puzzling bug in large code bases and this style of build system is in principle unsafe for that reason.
A remedy (or hack) that avoids much rethinking is to construct object file names
that encode the path-elements of the source files from which they are compiled, e.g.
objdir/srcdirA_file.o.
Also shaky is the grab whatever is there approach
to providing the source files. Better to list them explicitly, e.g.
SRC :=  src/cKeyboard.cpp \
        src/GUI_MainForm.cpp \
        ...
        

This may seem tedious and unclever if you make a late start on it, but once
you're uptodate it's no trouble to add new files and remove redundant ones
as occasions arise. A build system ought to nail down and make clear to its users exactly what
files, if any, should initially exist for each target. As it is, all anyone can see is that your build
system aims to build whatever program might, with luck, result from compiling and linking
whatever .c, .cpp files happen to lie anywhere in or under the src directory at
build time.

Thanks. Your suggestion about a working rule made me rethink at how the .o file list was missing the paths, which leaded me to a working solution. I'd be glad to hear your opinion on my own answer.
